# Different matrix multiplication result in MATLAB and Python leads different eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matrix-multiplication, eigenvector

I am trying to convert my MATLAB code to Python. I have to multiply two matrices and calculate the eigenvector and eigenvalues of the multiplication result. Here are the two matrices

```
P = [0.153833459882762  0.733552631578947;
     -0.911184210526316 -0.153833459882762];
Q = [0.649519052838329 3.09722222222222;
    -3.84722222222222 -0.649519052838329];
```

I get the following results in MATLAB

```
>>PQ = P*Q
PQ =
         -2.72222222222222                         0
     -1.11022302462516e-16         -2.72222222222222

>>[eigvec, eigval] = eig(PQ)
eigvec =
                         0         0.983547166232033
                         1         0.180651520328333
eigval =
         -2.72222222222222                         0
                         0         -2.72222222222222
```

Python is giving the following results using PyTorch

```
import torch
P = torch.tensor([[0.153833459882762, 0.733552631578947],
     [-0.911184210526316, -0.153833459882762]],dtype = torch.complex64)
Q = torch.tensor([[0.649519052838329, 3.09722222222222],
    [-3.84722222222222, -0.649519052838329]],dtype = torch.complex64)
PQ = P@Q
print(PQ)
torch.linalg.eig(PQ)
```

And the output is

```
tensor([[-2.7222e+00+0.j,  2.9802e-08+0.j],
        [ 1.1921e-07+0.j, -2.7222e+00+0.j]])
torch.return_types.linalg_eig(
eigenvalues=tensor([-2.7222+0.j, -2.7222+0.j]),
eigenvectors=tensor([[0.-0.j, 1.+0.j],
        [1.+0.j, 0.-0.j]]))
```

And the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using NumPy is

```
import numpy as np
np.linalg.eig(P@Q)
```

the eig result for numpy is

```
(array([-2.7222+0.j, -2.7222+0.j], dtype=complex64),
 array([[ 0.4472-0.j, -0.4472+0.j],
        [ 0.8944+0.j,  0.8944+0.j]], dtype=complex64))
```

It's evident that the multiplication results are different for MATLAB and Python. Also, I have different eigenvectors for MATLAB, Pytorch, and Numpy. The difference between Python and MATLAB may be because of the numerical precision of the floating point operation. But, it is changing the results completely. Why do Pytorch and Numpy have different eigenvectors? Is there any technique to align Python's results with MATLAB's?

Comment: (1) Those are not the eigenvectors you get in MATLAB. (2) The Python results seem to have been computed using PyTorch, in single-precision floating point? Please post a [mre] so we can see what you did. If I repeat your MATLAB computations in Python using NumPy, I get the same results (sufficiently close).

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I have edited the question. Hope it helps. MATLAB, Pytorch, and Numpy are giving completely different eigenvectors.

Comment: Yeah, both in PyTorch and in NumPy you are computing using single-precision floats (because `complex64` is single precision). Define `P` and `Q` as NumPy arrays with double precision floats (`float64` or `complex128`), and you’ll get better results there.

Comment: Also, when I ran your MATLAB code laat week, I got a different result from what you got.

Comment: Using double precision (`complex128`) with Pytoch/Numpy is giving the same results. Thanks, @CrisLuengo. BTW, what results did you get from MATLAB?

Comment: I see `eigvec = [1.0000, 0.2425; 0, 0.9701]`, the other stuff is the same as what you show.